# Photoshop toolbar sliders have huge increments when sliding with stylus

Tags: adobe, photoshop, tablet-pc, wacom, stylus-pen

Are there more than brush and opacity settings for a stylus in photoshop?

I recently hooked up a Huion 24" 4k display tablet to run with photoshop on my Windows PC. Works great so far but when adjusting values in the toolbars using the slider, the values have large steps. When i use the mouse it is normal. the steps are increments of one with the mouse but huge when using the stylus. It also varies depending on the toolbar slider. for example the
Clone Source toolbar (under the Window dropdown) when adjusting the values with the stylus the smallest % increment i can do is %80. so if i slide it all the way to 1 then move the slider over the next number is %81 then 161 and so on in increments of 80. Another toolbar, the brush angle, slides at %7 increments using the stylus and single digit increments when using the mouse.

I dont see it being a sensitivity or resolution issue as the steps are consistent within the slider but different depending on the slider. Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was behind on one update for photoshop. updated and I am no longer having the issue.